# What is the limit for the insert method in SDK writing to a BigQuery table

Tags: node.js, google-bigquery

I am using BigQuery library to insert rows to my table from my server. Example code is as follows:

```
const { BigQuery } = require('@google-cloud/bigquery');
const bqClient = new BigQuery();
const dataset = bqClient.dataset('events');

const tableName = process.env.ENV == 'prod' ? 'users' : 'users_staging';
const usersTable = dataset.table(tableName);

const logToBigQueryUsers = log => {
  usersTable.insert(log).then(res => {console.log(`inserted row for user id ${log.user_id}`)})
  .catch(err => {
    console.log(tableName+" bigquery error: ",JSON.stringify(err))
  })
}

module.exports = {logToBigQueryUsers}
```

My question is what are limits for this method? I have checked the limits in documentation, but I couldn't get which ones are valid for my case.

Thank you

Comment: which kind of limit do you want to know?

Comment: limits like 1000req/s or 100 method call per second

Comment: https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/quotas#streaming_inserts

Comment: So I should check streaming data limits when I use this method in SDK. Thank you, that was what I need.